# How to get the views related to a viewmodel in MugenMvvm

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.ios, mugenmvvmtoolkit

How can I get the view related to a viewmodel in Xamarin.Ios in combination with Mugen Mvvm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved the problem, there is a ViewModelToViewConverter build in.

```
var view = ViewModelToViewConverter.Instance.Convert(viewModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `IViewAwareViewModel` in MugenMvvm has a `View` property you can use.

Otherwise there seems to be an extension method [`GetCurrentView<T>()`](https://github.com/MugenMvvmToolkit/MugenMvvmToolkit/blob/5a14db2ab03656e3e6623ca11bddffbc1ced986d/Core/MugenMvvmToolkit.Core(NetStandard)/Extensions/ViewModelExtensions.cs#L87) which gives you the View of the ViewModel.

Comment: Yes but it that method you have to know wich view you want to get back. I have a list of different viewmodels that I need to resolve into views

Comment: You can just use `object` for `T`, then check the type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [IViewMappingProvider.FindMappingForViewModel](https://github.com/MugenMvvmToolkit/MugenMvvmToolkit/blob/master/Core/MugenMvvmToolkit.Core(NetStandard)/Interfaces/IViewMappingProvider.cs) method to get view type by view model type or to create view for view model you can use the [IViewManager.GetOrCreateView](https://github.com/MugenMvvmToolkit/MugenMvvmToolkit/blob/master/Core/MugenMvvmToolkit.Core(NetStandard)/Interfaces/IViewManager.cs).